# JQuery/Ajax Form Validation not Inserting into Database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I have a PHP form that inserts data into database after user clicks submit.

Works perfectly - so i added in some validation via Jquery to make certain fields required to fill out by user

Validation works too. When user tries to submit form with incomplete fields, the system will show error message and not allow user to continue.

My issue is that after all the validation errors have been corrected, my form won't actually insert any data into my database after submit.  The submit will go through and redirect user to a new page as I intended, but no data is actually submitted to my database.

Not sure what could be the problem?

Here is my user.php page:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //all my INSERT INTO/UPDATE queries//    
}
?>

<body>
    <button id="addproduct" class="add">Add+</button>
    <form action="user.php" method="POST" id="insert_form">
        <p>Game #</p><input type="number" placeholder="0" name="gamenumber" class="gamenumber"></input>
        <div class="bottomrow">
            <h1>HOME</h1>
            <h2></h2>
            <h1>AWAY</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="logos">
            <div id="home-logo"></div>
            <div id="away-logo"></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="teamhomerow">
            <select name="hometeam" id="logoz" class="team">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <?php foreach ($results2 as $result2) { ?>
                    <option value="<?= $result2['id']; ?>"><?= $result2['name']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="teamawayrow">
            <select name="awayteam" id="logoz2" class="team">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <?php foreach ($results2 as $result2) { ?>
                    <option value="<?= $result2['id']; ?>"><?= $result2['name']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="toprow">
            <input type="number" name="homescore" placeholder="0" class="team-score">
            <div class="versus"><img src="versus.png" alt=""></div>
            <input type="number" name="awayscore" placeholder="0" class="team-score">
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" id="reg" name="result" value="reg">
            <label for="reg">REG</label>
            <input type="radio" id="ot" name="result" value="ot">
            <label for="ot">OT</label>
            <input type="radio" id="so" name="result" value="so">
            <label for="so">SO</label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="wrapper"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
    </form>
    <span id="error"></span>
    <table id="item_table">
        <tr></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Here is my Jquery for the dynamic option menus. This is without validation. Inserts into database perfectly: (the 'fil_players.php' is just another php page with some SELECT queries.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var count = 0; //start count at 0
  $(document).on("click", ".add", function () {
    count++;
    var html = "";
    html +=
      '<div class="goal"><select name="teamzzz[]" class="teamz" data-playerz="' +
      count +
      '"><option value="">Team</option><?php echo fill_select_box($pdo, "0"); ?></select>';
    html +=
      '<select class="goalz" name="playerzzz[]" id="playermenu' +
      count +
      '"> <option value="">Player</option></select>';
    html +=
      '<select class="assistz" name="assistzzz[]" id="assistmenu' +
      count +
      '"> <option value="">Assist</option> </select>';
    html +=
      '<button type="button" name="remove" class="remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">REMOVE</span></button></div>';
    $(".wrapper").append(html);
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".remove", function () {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
  });
  $(document).on("change", ".teamz", function () {
    var teamidz = $(this).val();
    var playeridz = $(this).data("playerz");
    $.ajax({
      url: "fill_players.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        team_idz: teamidz,
      },
      success: function (data) {
        var html = '<option value="">Player</option>';
        html += data;
        $("#playermenu" + playeridz).html(html);
        $("#assistmenu" + playeridz).html(html);
      },
    });
  });
  //validation part//
});
```

Now here is where I added my validation. I put it right underneath As mentioned above, it will catch and display errors. But when i fix them and click submit, nothing actually gets inserts into my database. I just get redirected to the correct page after submit  (user.php - where all my INSERT queries are) with no new data in my database.

Here is my validation added at bottom of script after 'validation part':

```
$("#insert_form").on("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var error = "";
  $(".teamz").each(function () {
    var count = 1;
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      error += "<p>Select team at " + count + " row</p>";
      return false;
    }
    count = count + 1;
  });
  $(".goalz").each(function () {
    var count = 1;
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      error += "<p>Select goal " + count + " Row</p> ";
      return false;
    }
    count = count + 1;
  });
  $(".assistz").each(function () {
    var count = 1;
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      error += "<p>Enter assist at " + count + " Row</p>";
      return false;
    }
    count = count + 1;
  });
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  if (error == "") {
    $.ajax({
      url: "user.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: form_data,
      success: function (data) {
        window.location = "user.php";
        if (data == "ok") {
          $("#item_table").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
          $("#error").html(
            '<div class="alert alert-success">Item Details Saved</div>'
          );
        }
      },
    });
  } else {
    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + error + "</div>");
  }
});
```

I have a feeling like this has something to do with the on.submit function possibly? I've tried removing the on.submit function but then the submit button doesn't work at all. I think this is somehow conflicting with my regular PHP insert queries and can't seem to find the solution.

I do believe i just need to make a small tweak in my ajax/jquery. Any help is much appreciated

UPDATE: Barmar found the solution which was:

```
var form_data = $(this).serialize() + '&submit=1';
```

My only problem is if the user doesn't add those dynamic options to begin with, the form still will not post. That is because the line below is only telling it to post IF there are no errors....but what if the variables didn't even exist in the first place?

I think it's related to this line below, right after the serialize line:

```
if(error == '')
```

I tried to do something like below but it did not work:

```
if(error == '') || (error == 'undefined')
```

Comment: 1) Debug the request in the browser. 2) Debug the `$_POST` variable in PHP.

Comment: 1. NEVER call anything "submit" in a form so rename that. 2. If you ajax the form then your ajax does not actually send the "submit" so `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ` fails. Send it after renaming it in page and PHP

Comment: Or use `var form_data = $(this).serialize() + '&submit=1'` to add the `submit` parameter.

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for your advice. I actually did try that too and still had the same problem :/ May have done it wrong though so I'll keep this in mind for next time

Comment: @Barmar so only problem is if i don't add those dynamic options to begin with, it still will not insert data. Only if i add those options and there are no errors will it work.

I updated my code at the bottom - i think i need to also tell it to post if those options were never added. Do you know if there's an easy fix around this?

Comment: I don't see any problem with `if (error == '')`. It means you'll only send the AJAX request if there were no errors. It has nothing to do with what gets sent in the AJAX request.

Comment: Your validation code is calling `user.php` instead of `fill_players.php`.

Comment: @Barmar yeah you're right it just has to do with all fields not being submitted. i just realized my errors were somehow turned off so i havent been receiving any notices lol. Gonna figure out how to turn these back on and take a look -